# What should I read to understand the New Deal coalition?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century

I'm interested in learning about the history and the structure of the New Deal coalition formed during the 30s up until its end in the 60s from an academic perspective, particularly with regards to who were the main figures and the main corporate and political actors involved in efforts to either maintain it or destroy it. I realize this might be a vague question (my bad!), but I'm not looking for anything too specific, mostly just an introductory (beyond wikipedia-level) reference dealing with the coalition instead of the reforms with the same name.

I've read through Howard Zinn's A People's History of the United States and have a very general sense of the period from spending some time on Wikipedia.

Comment: For free, I'd suggest start with reading the WikiPedia page on the [Fifth Party System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_Party_System), and then when you're done click the "New Deal Coalition" link on the bottom of the page and read that. Zinn ... well ... I'd call it an *important* read, but its very dry going. The man wasn't exactly an engaging writer. Good for you getting through it.

Comment: In particular, you're going to have a lot of trouble on some of the details of the New Deal coalition, because one bedrock pillar of it was Southern White Supremacists, and pretty much everyone is afraid to write openly about that, unprotected by humbug. Zinn is one of the few exceptions.

Comment: We discourage [reference requests](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/are-requests-for-references-appropriate-on-history-stack-exchangerevisited); they generate more discussion than answers.  What would happen if you altered the question to (as I understand it) what you actually want to know, "Who was in the New Deal coalition?"  or "What was the New Deal coalition?"  (Assume that all answers will include references)

Comment: @MCW Thank you very much for spending the time! I will keep all of these in mind, and will read the mentioned references.

Comment: If all you really want to know about is books, well, we generally encourage opinion-oriented chatter go to our chat rooms. The permanent one available for anything is [The Time Machine](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1560/the-time-machine)